# Xamarin.Forms InvalidCastException in MainActivity

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have ran into this issue when I finally fix my Android simulator. I have neglected the android project a bit and have now run into this issue and I'm unable to find the cause. This error occurs when we start the android project. [image] I haven't seen this problem in the MainActivity before, only in pages that have conflicting controls. When I click in to see if there is an inner exception, there is no inner exception and the stack trace isn't much help. [image]
I'm not sure what the issue is in this instance and I'm unsure how to debug this problem further. I'm using Xamarin Studio for Mac and I'm using the android sim provided by the android SDK. The iOS project builds and runs as intended. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems similar to an issue I had. My problem was build target not matching the xamarin version I had. Make sure all your droid projects target the latest framework and that your nuget packages are all up to date. Looks like you have Android.Support.V4 in the bottom screenshot and Android.Support.V7 in the top screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think it turned out to be an issue with my simulator. I cleared the cache on the next startup and it finally loaded it.